# Phone camera (Samsung S4): is it possible to determine the distance to the object in focus on jpg picture?

Tags: focal-length, smartphone

I took a picture with Samsung S4 phone. Is it possible to determine the distance to the object on the picture?

The object is in focus. I looked at the JPG picture properties but could not find anything indicating to the distance. The focal length is fixed on this camera, it's 31mm in 35mm equivalent scale.

Comment: Do you know the size of the object?

Comment: @mattdm, no. In fact the reason I'm looking for a distance is to determine the size

Comment: That makes a big difference to the answers.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this equation:

```
Distance of an object (in meters) =

   (focal length (mm) * object height (m) * image height (px))
   -----------------------------------------------------------
       (object height in image (px) * sensor height (mm))
```

Comment: See the comments. Size of object is not known.

Comment: @mattdm ah! well 2 unknown variables is a a problem, hope OP can estimate one of them. gotta work with what you have!

Answer (score 0):

If it is in the file, exiftool will tell you.

If not, there is no easy way to tell the distance as cameras basically record angle information (in the picture - each pixel looks at a specific direction from an idealized center). If you have two or more photos from different viewpoints, then you could use PanoTools or similar tools to create a 3D mesh, and if you know some physical lengths then you could derive the distance to your object. (And you know some physical locations: your eye or camera level, and also the ground level, let's not forget it).

Comment: thanks, i'm surprised that cameras do not record auto-focus information.

Comment: Well - they record focal length and in-focus indicators. :-) But distance to subject needs triangulation, so two pictures.

Comment: @TFuto - it doesn't need triangulation.  It does however need to know the exact stetting of the focus and the atmospheric conditions.  Focus can change slightly based on humidity and such and generally lenses don't measure the exact position of the focus.  If you did know the exact setting of the focus though, then the distance to subject can be calculated without any triangulating.

Comment: @AJHenderson: Your reasoning is only valid if the person uses an extremely shallow depth-of-field, like one in microscopes (a long teleobjective is a good approximation). If he is using large DOF and not long focal length, the successive approximation or heuristics of focusing just gets a good enough focus lock. Imagine a very extreme scenario: an ultra wide angle lens. That has focus from 30 cm to infinity. So okay, you have a focus lock, but the relative error is so big, that data is not useful. My opinion...

Comment: @TFuto - focusing works by finding the maximum contrast.  Yes, the wider the depth of field, the more will be acceptably in focus, but down to whatever level of sensitivity the AF sensor can handle, it will still get closer than what the depth of field range is in most cases, if not a relatively exact measure.  Almost certainly within the variance you will get from environmental conditions outright.

Comment: @AJHenderson: I have a different viewpoint on this. If you take a wide angle lens, and want to manually focus, you will be able to manually focus in a wide range without noticeable change in focus quality. Mirror-down sensors use phase, which is not as precise as a full frame contrast focus. Also, the sensors have a certain precision, and the original question was about an S4. :-) And finally, focus has a mechanical drag and error by itself. So where the focus ring stops, we can only guess. :-).

Comment: @AJHenderson: And actually, I think you got it wrong about the DOF issue. ("it will still get closer than what the depth of field range is in most cases") Of course! What I am saying is: the larger DOF there is, the harder is to find the exact position for focus, and actually the less it is needed to find that so exactly. (Shallower DOF means it is easier to see that objects are not completely in focus.)

Comment: @TFuto - I think perhaps we aren't disagreeing as much as we think.  I agree that the wider dof will make it less accurate, but the accuracy of "ideal focus" vs the accuracy of the point of "out of focus" are going to be the same.  Triangulation still doesn't gain anything, just the wider the DOF, the lower accuracy is possible unless the AF is sensitive enough that it can still determine the focus point exactly.

Comment: @AJHenderson: "going to be the same": the relative error is going to be the same, so abs(dist_ideal - dist_out_of_focus)/dist_ideal is kind of constant (not considering hyperfocal stuff). Meaning: 1. the farther the object is away, the larger the absolute error is. Consequently, 2. the larger the DOF is, the larger the potential absolute focusing error is. You are right about relative error.

Comment: @AJHenderson: With triangulation, you control the distance between two cameras, and a large set or related point pairs can be determined, and this and the camera positions create a 3D mapping that is as precise as the intersections of virtual rays emanating from the two cameras. The farther the cameras are apart and the larger the resolution is, the smaller these 3D intersections are, and this is the resolution of the triangulation. It is a much more precise way to determine positions than single viewpoint + contrast detection.

Comment: Triangulation requires accurate distance measurement. It doesn't determine accurate distance. Unless you have some way of using the cameras that I'm not thinking of.

Comment: @AJHenderson: Triangulation requires only one accurate distance measurement, and then it WILL determine accurate distances by definition (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangulation). You have the distance between the two cameras. E.g. imagine you take two photos from two different points. You use PanoTools to create a 3D representation. That will create a model which is fully realistic, except it needs a scale. And that you can provide various ways, the easiest if you tell the distance between the cameras. Your camera is a very fine angle meter, let's not forget that. :-)

Comment: Ah using the relative angles it the scene to determine relative angle. OK. I'm on board now.

Comment: does anyone know why exactly smartphone cameras do not report the focus position of the lens? it seems like an easy thing to do to me.

Answer (score 0):

Most lenses don't measure the position of the focus, just which direction they need to move in order to reach focus.  Therefore they can't measure the exact position of the focus.  If the data isn't already in the EXIF information of the photo, then it likely is not able to be captured by the camera.

Comment: it makes a sense then, i was wondering why don't they report the position of the focus. i'd love to look at low level specifications of the phone cameras